# How to communicate with a jade agent form an external application using RMI or sockets

Tags: sockets, rmi, agents-jade

Help please!.

How can I communicate with a jade agent form an external application using RMI or java sockets ?.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jade agents are objects inside a jade platform. Every agent has a lifecycle (setup, action, take down). Communicating between agents in a container/platform or between agents in different containers/platforms is done with ACL messaging protocol and its completely handled by jade framework, so you normally won't need to use sockets or RMI to communicate between agents, but if your agents need to communicate with any external application, it's completely possible (and completely NOT recommended), you can do it within any of your agent behaviours `action` method. For instance something like this:

```
public class MyAgent extends Agent {

    @Override
    protected void setup()
    {
        super.setup();

        addBehaviour(new CommunicateBehaviour());
    }

    private class CommunicateBehaviour extends OneShotBehaviour {

        @Override
        public void action() {
            // TODO: add your code to handle socket/RMI communication here
            Socket client = new Socket("YOUR_SERVER_ADDR", YOUR_SERVER_PORT);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that every agent in jade runs over only a single thread, so if your agent has more than one behaviour, any blocking operation in any of its behaviours will cause starvation in execution of other behaviours and you should take care about that when working with blocking socket operations.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I can see why being single threaded means interacting with another application could be a bad idea for an agent. But is there any way for a human to send messages to an agent that can be handled as if it was communicating with another agent?

i.e. a game where all the characters are agents, except one agent is managed by a human player